# Masking data from intelitrace log file

Tags: intellitrace

I am using Intellirace to get production error in the itrace log file. Client is having concern doing so, once concern is the client data (like the SSN , Name, Telephone numbers etc.  Is there any way i can mask the client data from the intrellrace .itrace log file before using it for historic debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masking certain data in .ITrace file currently isn't a supported scenario. 
On the other hand, IntelliTrace won't collect raw memory and only collect limited data in call stack. Even under "call and event" mode it collects parameters but won't go deeper than one level. IntelliTrace file is less likely to carry sensitive data comparing to traditional dump files.